# Moсkk. Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize. For tests Dispatchers.setMain from kotlinx-coroutines-test module can be used

Tags: kotlin, junit

I'm trying to write a test for a method that contains asynchronous calls.

[image]

```
fun openIntercom(intercomId: String, onCompletable: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            apiRepository.openIntercomByJWT(intercomId.toInt()).apply {
                if (this != null && this.status.equals("ok")) {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { onCompletable(true) }
                } else {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { onCompletable(false) }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e, "[openIntercom] error")
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { onCompletable(false) }
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
fun `openIntercom and return success`() = runTest{
    val viewModel = IntercomMainViewModel(apiRepository)

    coEvery { apiRepository.openIntercomByJWT(any()) } returns StatusResponseData("ok")

    var result = false
    viewModel.openIntercom("123") { b ->
        result = b
    }

    Assert.assertEquals(true, result)
}
```

But I get an error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize. For tests Dispatchers.setMain from kotlinx-coroutines-test module can be used.

If I remove runTest{} then I get an error: io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: ApiRepository(#1).openIntercomByJWT(123, continuation {})

What am I doing wrong?

I added:

```
class TestViewModelScopeRule(
private val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()) :TestWatcher() {
override fun starting(description: Description?) {
    super.starting(description)
    Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
}

override fun finished(description: Description?) {
    super.finished(description)
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
}}

testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to apply rule?
Like this

@get:Rule
val dispatcherRule = TestViewModelScopeRule()